# Jenkins - run long job nightly if new work done?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Right now, I have two sets of benchmarks, a short one and a long one. The short one runs on checkin for every branch. Which set to run is a parameter - SHORT or LONG. The long one always runs nightly on the dev branch. How can I trigger other branches to build and run the long benchmark if the branch was built successfully today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run those long tests only over the night - I find it easiest to just duplicate the job and modify it so its triggered in the night and has additional checks added after the normal job, I.e. your post-commit jobs just do the short test, the nightly triggered do the short first and then (if no errors) the long one.

I find that much easier to handle then the added complexity of chaining jobs on some condition, like evaluating time of day to skip some tests.

Example 1st job that runs after every commit

```
node() {
  stage('Build') {
    // Build
  }
  stage('Short Test') {
    // Short Test
  }
}
```

2nd job that triggers nightly

```
node() {
  stage('Build') {
    // Build
  }
  stage('Short Test') {
    // Short Test, fail the build here when not successful
  }
  stage('Long Tests')
    // Long Test, runs only when short test successful
  }
}
```

### Edit

A solution that got it all in a single job, however it adds alot of complexity and makes some followup use cases harder to integrate, i.e. different notification for the integration test branch, tracking of build durations etc. I still find it more manageable to have it split in 2 jobs.

Following job must be configured to be triggered by post commit hook **and** a nightly timer. It runs the long test when

1. the last build is younger then set (you dont want it to trigger from the last nightly),
2. last run was successful (dont want to run long test for a broken build), and
3. was triggered by said timer (dont want to trigger on a check in).

```groovy
def runLongTestMaxDiffMillis = 20000
def lastRunDiff = (currentBuild.getStartTimeInMillis().toInteger() - currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().getStartTimeInMillis().toInteger())

def lastBuildTooOld = (lastRunDiff > runLongTestMaxDiffMillis)
def isTriggeredByTimer = currentBuild.getBuildCauses('hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger$TimerTriggerCause')
def lastBuildSuccessful = (currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().getResult() == 'SUCCESS')

def runLongTest = (!lastBuildTooOld && isTriggeredByTimer && lastBuildSuccessful)

node() {
    if (runLongTest) {
        println 'Running long test'
    } else {
        println 'Skipping long test'
    }
}
```

Comment: What would the checks look like?

Comment: I meant checks in the sense of tests. I will edit in some small example.

Comment: This is what I wound up doing. Jenkins does not make this easy.

Comment: Well, i will edit in a solution that achieves this, but its definitely alot more complex than another job. Also you get the results of the eventually long nightlies in the same overview as the shorter ones, makes tracking durations difficult etc. So you can do it, but its the question if you should.

Comment: It's a nice function for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another pipeline that calls the parameterized pipeline with the LONG parameter, for example:

```
stage('long benchmark') {
    build job: 'your-benchmark-pipeline', parameters: [string(name: 'type', value: 'LONG')]
}
```

When you configure this new pipeline you can tick the `Build after other projects are built` checkbox in the `Build Triggers` section and choose which short benchmarks should trigger it once they complete successfully (the default behavior).

Comment: This one looks good but how do I conditionally trigger it, if the other build has built in the last day?

Comment: You're right - it will only work on newer builds (builds that occurred after you created this pipeline). In addition you'll have to configure the original pipeline to run on a schedule with the dev branch as the default parameter. Anyway I think @Dominik's solution is better because its emphasis on simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Schedule Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Schedule+Build+Plugin) to schedule a build of the long job when the short job succeed.

The short job runs on every branch, when a build succeed for a certain branch, it schedules a build of the long job (in the night) with the branch in parameter, so the long job will run on this particular branch.